# How to write multiple lines as watermark?... and images with transparency?

Tags: watermark, draftwatermark

I want to write 2 or 3 lines in watermark

```
\usepackage{draftwatermark}
\SetWatermarkText{Mika Ike}
\SetWatermarkScale{0.25}
\SetWatermarkColor[gray]{0.88}
```

How can I write "Mika Ike" and under this line "mikaike@mikaike.mikaike" and a third lined with "At My house"  ?

Is it possible?

And... to use a image but with a hight level os transparency to see that image softly at background.

```
\usepackage{draftwatermark}
\SetWatermarkText{\includegraphics{fig1.jpg}}
\SetWatermarkScale{0.25}
\SetWatermarkColor[gray]{0.88}
```

Do you think this is the best package for watermarks?   or do you know other better than this?.

Could you tell me about other packages.

Comment: Have you tried `Mika Ike\\mikaike@mikaike.mikaike\\At My house`?  Also, one question per post, *please*.

Comment: @SeanAllred Yes, I tried. But I have no good results!!!   
all the text in one one line.

Comment: Use a `\parbox`

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Using the `draftwatermark` package, you can use a `\parbox`, or a `minipage`, to have the text spanning several lines:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a6paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{draftwatermark}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\SetWatermarkText{\parbox{12cm}{%
  Mika Ike \\
  \url{mikaike@mikaike.mikaike} \\ 
  At My house}}
\SetWatermarkScale{.5}
\SetWatermarkColor{red}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[4]\lipsum[4]
\lipsum[4]\lipsum[4]

\end{document}
```

[image]

In the case of opacity for images, the `draftwatermark` package apparently doesn't provide many possibilities.

As an alternative, I'd suggest you to use the [`background`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/background) package; since this package internally uses TikZ, you can easily control the attributes (opacity, color, position, etc.) for the background material. A little example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a6paper]{geometry}
\usepackage[scale=2.5,opacity=1,color=red]{background}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{varwidth}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\backgroundsetup{
contents={\begin{varwidth}{8cm}{%
  Mika Ike \\
  \url{mikaike@mikaike.mikaike} \\ 
  At My house}\end{varwidth}}
}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[4]\lipsum[4]
\lipsum[4]\lipsum[4]

\end{document}
```

The `varwidth` environment was used to have a box of adjustable width allowing multiple lines of text; a `minipage` or a `\parbox` could also have been used instead.

[image]

And, using an image:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a6paper]{geometry}
\usepackage[scale=1,opacity=0.75,angle=0]{background}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{varwidth}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\backgroundsetup{
contents={\includegraphics[height=\textheight,width=\textwidth,keepaspectratio]{ctanlion}}
}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[4]\lipsum[4]
\lipsum[4]\lipsum[4]

\end{document}
```

[image]

CTAN lion drawing by Duane Bibby.

Comment: I don't think the `background` package was the important part of this answer; I also tried it and, without `varwidth`, the problem persisted.  Particularly, this solution also works with `\SetBgContents` from the same package, and various other methods (eg TikZ).  (Very nice solution, though!!!)

Comment: @SeanAllred I added a little remark about the use of `varwidth`. `\SetBgContents` was the old syntax from the first version of the package (which still can be used), before I adopted a key=value approach.

Answer (score 6):

One solution is to use `\shortstack{}` which can be found in the manual of the [draftwatermark](http://ctan.math.illinois.edu/macros/latex2e/contrib/draftwatermark/draftwatermark.pdf) package.

Example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{draftwatermark}
\SetWatermarkText{
  \shortstack{
        \includegraphics[scale=0.8]{ctan_lion_600.png} 
  }
}
\SetWatermarkScale{0.15}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\lipsum[2]
\lipsum[3]
\lipsum[4]
\end{document}
```

Example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{draftwatermark}
\SetWatermarkText{
  \shortstack{
        this is the first line  \\[1em]  second line 
  }
}
\SetWatermarkScale{2}
\SetWatermarkColor[gray]{0.5}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\lipsum[2]
\lipsum[3]
\lipsum[4]
\end{document}
```

[image]
[image]